# ISNULL what happens when the replacement value is NULL?

Tags: sql-server, null

If the values in `MyTable.MyColumn` and `@MyVar` are `NULL`, what does the following statement return?

`ISNULL(@MyVar, MyTable.MyColumn)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
create table MyTable
(
  MyColumn int
)

insert into MyTable default values

declare @MyVar int

select ISNULL(@MyVar, MyTable.MyColumn)
from MyTable
```

Result:

```
-----------
NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

Others have explained what happens. Solutions in case you don't want those Nulls.

- If the expression is in the `SELECT` list - and you don't want `NULL` to appear in the result, you can use the `COALESCE()` function which can take more than 2 parameters:

  ```
  COALESCE(@MyVar, MyTable.MyColumn, another_value)
  ```
- If you have it in a condition, like you mention in the comments:

  ```
  WHERE MyTable.MyColumn = ISNULL(@MyVar, MyTable.MyColumn)
  ```

  you can replace it with (assuming you want the condition to hold `TRUE` when `@MyVar` is null, no matter if `MyTable.MyColumn`  is null or not):

  ```
  WHERE (MyTable.MyColumn = @MyVar OR @MyVar IS NULL)
  ```

Answer (score 3):

It will return NULL, of course. :) Quite easy to test too. What's the overall need for this? If you need to for example ensure that at least some value is returned, you have a few options. For example case:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @MyVar IS NULL 
   THEN ISNULL(MyTable.MyColumn, 'replacementvalue') 
   ELSE @MyVar
END AS RESULT
FROM MyTable
```

We need to know more about the real issue here.

Comment: inherited code, seems this was put in with the assumption that `MyColumn` is not nullable. due to a bug elsewhere, some records in `MyColumn` now have `Null` values. It was on where statement `Where MyTable.MyColumn = ISNULL(@MyVar,MyTable.MyColumn)` thanks for the test :)

Comment: Np, just realised after I committed that response, that you can probably just do ISNULL(ISNULL(@MyVar, MyTable.MyColumn), 'replacementvalue') too which may perform either way, but is a lot simpler to type and read. But ok, GL with that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-)

```
select ISNULL(null,null)
```